# 500 (Internal Server Error) ajax calling

Tags: php, ajax, timeout, internal-server-error

Internal error occurs when the site is on server, on localhost it works fine.  The code is as given below.

> GET http://www.olbx.in/classified/extract_handler_post.php 500 (Internal Server Error)x.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6x.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6(anonymous function) @ books-classified:281(anonymous function) @ books-classified:345

Increasing the timeout time did not help out

The complete error:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '../classified/extract_handler_post.php',
    data: SendInfo,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    success: function (data) {
        count =  data['count'] ;

        for ( i = 0 ; i < count ;i++ ) {
            // $("#details").append(data['data'][i]['author']);
            //if (data['data'][i]['category']=="Books"){


                var iDiv = document.createElement('div');

                iDiv.id = 'block';
                iDiv.className = 'grid_12';
                document.getElementsByTagName('article')[0].appendChild(iDiv);

                // Now create and append to iDiv
                var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
                innerDiv.className = 'grid_2 alpha';

                // The variable iDiv is still good... Just append to it.
                iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
                if (data['data'][i]['source'] == "Flipkart"){
                innerDiv.innerHTML =  '<img src=../images/classifiedlist/flipkart_logo.png ></img>';

                }
                else if (data['data'][i]['source'] == "Landmark"){
                innerDiv.innerHTML =  '<img src=../images/classifiedlist/landmark_logo.png ></img>';

                }
                else if (data['data'][i]['source'] == "Amazon"){
                innerDiv.innerHTML =  '<img src=../images/classifiedlist/Amazon-India-Logo.png ></img>';

                }
                else if (data['data'][i]['source'] == "RediffBooks"){
                innerDiv.innerHTML =  '<img src=../images/classifiedlist/rediff_logo.png ></img>';

                }


                    // Now create and append to iDiv
                var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
                innerDiv.className = 'grid_10 omega';


                // The variable iDiv is still good... Just append to it.
                iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);

                innerDiv.innerHTML = data['data'][i]['source'] +"<br/>Bookname: " + data['data'][i]['title'] + "<br/> List Price: " + data['data'][i]['mrp'] + " &nbsp; &nbsp; Sale Price:  " + data['data'][i]['available_price'] +" <br/><a href=" + data['data'][i]['url']  +">Shop now </a> <br/> <br/>" ;

            }
```

Comment: Is an PHP error, so I think that the problem is in extract_handler_post.php

Comment: as @jpintor has said, it is certainly a problem with the `extract_handler_post.php` script. Please post that, along with the contents of the server error log (should be /var/log/apache2/error.log or something similar)